# xamarin form button background color in custom renderer

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set the background color in xamarin form. To achieve that I thought I might use CustomRenderer. I want to set the background color from Hex value. Below is my code where I am finding hard to set the background color. I want to set it in windows 8.1 and UWP. I will really appreciate if some one can tell me on how do it in android as well.

```
[assembly: ExportRendererAttribute(typeof(PrimaryButton), typeof(PrimaryButtonRenderer))]

namespace ShareSpecial.Windows
{
    public class PrimaryButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BackgroundColor = //some color from hex string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Color class in Xamarin Forms has a method FromHex, and you can easily implement extension methods for color conversion in each platform. in Android there is already a default implementation named ToAndroid().

**For WP8 and UWP:**

Define this extension:

```
   static class ConvertExtensions
    {
        public static Windows.UI.Color ToWindowsColor(this Color color)

        {

            return Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb((byte)(color.A * 255), (byte)(color.R * 255), (byte)(color.G * 255), (byte)(color.B * 255));
        }
    }
```

And the code of your renderer would be:

```
Control.BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromHex("ffffffff").ToWindowsColor());
```

**For Android**:

If you change the backgroundColor using *SetBackgroundColor()* method, you will lose the effect of click, to keep it, use the below code:

```
            Color backgroundColor = Color.FromHex("ffffffff");
            int num = backgroundColor.ToAndroid().ToArgb();
            int num2 = backgroundColor.MultiplyAlpha(0.5).ToAndroid().ToArgb();
            base.Control.SupportBackgroundTintList = new ColorStateList(ColorExtensions.States, new int[] {
            num,
            num2
        });
```

You will have to extend your renderer from: *Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer*

Comment: I wan't to apply other effects like mouse enter and mouse leave and really don't want to pollute my xaml with that. You forgot to to provide code for ToWindowsColor thought I know what you are doing but it will be good to put the code for future reference for someone else

Comment: ToWindowsColor is defined by Xamarin.Forms.WinRT, you can reference it directly from your renderer.

Comment: Sorry, I just checked, and it appears that it's internal. the answer contains its implementation.

Comment: This approach works fine in UWP, Windows 8 but not working well in Android and it also changes the width of button in android, Any thoughts?

Comment: I provided a sample code for Android, I don't think that these changes will impact the width of the button, and I tested it, I think that another part of your code is what changing the width.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate finally got it working and posted my working solution but accepting your's as answer coz you pointed me in right direction and gave the actual working code. Thanks once again

Comment: Just wondering if you got the code for Ios also or a pointer to some resources for that. I have plularsight subscription also but that didn't help

Comment: Try this code:  Control.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("").ToUIColor();

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SolidColorBrush` for setting a color of Windows Platform element.

Control.BackgroundColor = ToWindowsBrush(Color.Red);

Here is a method that converts `Xamarin.Froms.Color` to `SolidColorBrush`

```
    public static SolidColorBrush ToWindowsBrush(Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
    {
        if (color.A < 0)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);

        var winColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb((byte)(color.A * 255), 
                                                 (byte)(color.R * 255),
                                                 (byte)(color.G * 255),
                                                 (byte)(color.B * 255));
        return new SolidColorBrush(winColor);
    }
```

Comment: I tried similar sort of approach but Windows.UI reference is not happy. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with help from @Hichaam and posting the working android solution

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ShareSpecial.Utils.Controls;
using ShareSpecial.Droid.Custom.Control.Buttons;
using Android.Content.Res;

[assembly: ExportRendererAttribute(typeof(SuccessButton), typeof(SuccessButtonRenderer))]
namespace ShareSpecial.Droid.Custom.Control.Buttons
{
    public class SuccessButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer
    {
        public SuccessButtonRenderer() { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> changeEvent)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(changeEvent);

            var backgroundColor = Color.FromHex("43ac6a");

            int num = backgroundColor.ToAndroid().ToArgb();

            int num2 = backgroundColor.MultiplyAlpha(0.5).ToAndroid().ToArgb();

            Control.SupportBackgroundTintList = new ColorStateList(ColorExtensions.States, new int[] { num, num2 });

            Control.SetTextColor(Color.FromHex("#ffffff").ToAndroid());
        }
    }
}
```